# Can you alias a method name in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

Consider I have some simple class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    T first() const { return this->m_first; }
    T second() const { return this->m_second; }
private:
    T m_first;
    T m_second;
}
```

Now I want to create some meaning behind some of that:

```cpp
typedef Vector<int> Position;
typedef Vector<unsigned int> Dimension;
```

Can I also create an alias to the methods of the new types Position and Dimension so that for Position, x() references frist(), y() references second() while for Dimension width() references first(), height() references second().

Or even more "speedy": Having first and second public, create aliases to the member variables? Real use case is more complex, but this should display what I want: Two things that are very similar in memory, but called completly different depending on the context.

Comment: you can use call backs either via `function pointers` or `std::funcntion` .  But why is position is of Int type and where are `x()` and `y()` defined and what will they do

Comment: u can't use a member function without an object. u could do that if the functions were static ones.

Comment: I would use inheritance if iwere u

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by doing something like this:

```
class Position : private Vector<int> {  
  public:
    auto x() const { return first(); }
    auto y() const { return second(); }
};

class Dimension : private Vector<unsigned int> {  
  public:
    auto width() const { return first(); }
    auto height() const { return second(); }
};
```

which creates new types that inherit from a specific instantiation of `Vector`, and call the privately inherited member functions with publicly accessible meaningful names.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6f6heE).

Comment: That sounds like a good idea but the compiled code actually enters the width() function and calls the first() function which seems like a waste of cycles - I would love for the compiler to take the hint and compile x() or width() to compile into a call to first() immediatly, even better just access the value of m_first without any function call inbetween.

Comment: @salbeira The compiler should be able to direct these calls to `first` and `second`, as long as you keep the definitions in the headers and compile with `-O2` or `/O2`.